# get number of unique mobile web customers

Tags: javascript, iphone, android, mobile, unique

I have a site optimized for mobile devices. I want to have a statistics of how many unique users from which device has accessed my site per day or per hour etc... is there a way in JavaScript that I can get some unique id about the device? can i get the phone number of the device?

tanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want develop your tracking system, then your real problem is unique consumer identification. And for this you could apply various techniques:

1) Use a cookie for tracking. If device or wap gateways don´t support cookies, then use url-identification.

2) Use HTTP hearders for getting unique ID. Here [useful](http://mobiforge.com/developing/blog/useful-x-headers) [links](http://certificateerror.blogspot.com/search?q=mobile%20operators%20headers&updated-max=2010-08-29T15:36:00%2b02:00&max-results=20).

3) Use some service for identification, some aggregators and carriers have it.

If you need it for statistics, then use some analytics system. You can use google analytics, but using server to server. Because many mobile don´t have good javascript support.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that there are only so many "unique identifiers" you can collect from a user (assuming you don't give them a cookie):

1. **IP Address**
   This can be spoofed via proxies, and some users have dynamic IP addresses, which change every time they connect. (Also, I've heard horror stories where sometimes the IP address changes *in between queries to your server.*)
2. **User Agent**
   Extremely easy to spoof. Also, it changes if the same user switches browsers.

Also as far as I know, there is no way for JavaScript to access the client's phone number, definitely not without their express permission. Thank god.

Comment: can't I get Model, Serial Number or MEID?

Comment: If the phone allows you to know model, that would be in the User Agent string (I believe). I'm pretty sure there's no way for JavaScript to just get the serial number or MEID.

Comment: Some ISP do change the IP while you are browsing.  In any case, IP addresses are highly unreliable for unique visitor counting.  User agent is not unique.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Google Analytics - http://analytics.google.com/

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of mobile centered web analytics tools out there now.

The best one in my opinion in Percent Mobile, they offer a free plan that has limited comercial use, but the comercial plans are priced not so high, it's worth it if this is important to you.

http://percentmobile.com/

Other popular option although I haven't personally tested:
http://bango.com/

**EDIT**: Another popular one:
http://www.flurry.com